# Shareaholic Social Bookmarking Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I've used `shareaholic` in the past and found it pretty good but they must have recently changed their formats which look great but `are not` functioning properly on my website.

The problems are:

1. The bookmarks are only showing the first row (not clearing the top row to show the second)
2. It's adding a background color to all of my  links

Any ideas what the problem is and solutions?

Answer (score -1):

I have the exact same problem..... I think Shareaholic is going down the toilet... Just look at what they did to 7.2. A very simplistic and stupid plugin. 6.1 was way better!

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure it's going down the toilet exactly, I like the new format with counters but I just wish it would function properly. I tried to get in touch with them directly but heard nothing back - I'm using another plugin at the moment but it only has Facebook & Twitter so not very effective in comparison